# i want to create a variable in perl of different length from 1 to 255

Tags: perl, variables

Like how we use a regex to match a variable, instead i want to use regex to assign variable-length to my variable.

eg: lets take a counter `$i`, which `$i` run in a for loop

```
for($i=0; $i < 256; $i++)
{
   $myVariable = a{$i};
}
```

i want `$myVariable` to be of different length, based on the counter variable `$i`

for instance, if `$i` is 5, then `$myVariabe` should be `"aaaaa"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for my $i (1..255) {
   my $myVariable = 'a' x $i;
   ...
}
```

or

```
my $myVariable;
for my $i (1..255) {
   $myVariable .= 'a';
   ...
}
```